# How do I subtract Maybe values in Haskell? For example, if I want to subtract Just 8 - Just 5 to get Just 3, how would I do that?

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

How can I do the following. For example, if I want to subtract `Just 8` - `Just 5` to get `Just 3`, how would I do that?

```
Just 8 - Just 5 = Just 3

Just 15 - Just 9 = Just 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Control.Applicative

main = print $ liftA2 (-) (Just 8) (Just 5)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how it would be used? I tried it and get the error 'variable not in scope'

Comment: I’m sure the OP would appreciate a little explanation WRT functors, applicatives, or lifting functions...

Comment: @Kau yes, but for the future, I suggest [you ask Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=liftA2) in situations like this.

Answer (score 6):

The `liftA2` function (imported from `Control.Applicative`) "lifts" an ordinary function into an `Applicative` context. `liftA2 (-)`, for example, is a function that takes not two `Num a => a` values, but two `(Applicative f, Num a) => f a` values, and produces a result in the same context. This works not just for `Maybe`:

```
>>> liftA2 (-) (Just 8) (Just 5)
Just 3
```

but for lists

```
>>> liftA2 (-) [4,5,6] [1,2,3] -- difference of every pair with one number from each list
[3,2,1,4,3,2,5,4,3]
```

`Either`:

```
>>> liftA2 (-) (Right 8) (Right 5)
Right 3
```

functions

```
>>> liftA2 (-) (+3) (*2) 9 -- (\x -> (x + 3) - (x * 2)) 9 == 12 - 18
-6
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use monad comprehensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}

foo :: (Num b, Monad m) => m b -> m b -> m b
foo a b = [ x - y | x <- a, y <- b ]
```

Nice, visual, underrated.

`foo (Just 8) (Just 5)` returns `Just 3`.

Of course in such a simple case it is a syntactical overkill, you're much better off with `liftA2 (-)` both semantically and practically.

Where monad comprehensions really shine is when you have some conditional computation. The classic example is safe division, avoiding the *divide-by-zero* errors:

```
safediv :: (MonadPlus m, Fractional b, Eq b) 
        => m b -> m b -> m b
safediv a b = [ x / y | x <- a, y <- b, y /= 0 ]

-- safediv (Just 8) (Just 0)  returns  Nothing
```

This is an *essentially* monadic operation, it can't be coded with applicatives, and any other alternative way to write it down is bound to be more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

In general you are expected to use a monadic approach:

```
Just 8 >>= \n -> Just 5 >>= \m -> return (n-m)
```

However without getting into monads we might still do this job by using functor and applicative instances of `Maybe` type.

First let's `fmap` the `(-)` operator over `Just 8` value, like `(-) <$> Just 8`. This would result in an applicative of `Maybe` type which is `Just (8-)` with type signature `Just (8-) :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)`. Now it just takes a single applicative operation to complete the job:

```
λ> (-) <$> (Just 8) <*> (Just 5) 
Just 3
```

This is sometimes done by `LiftA2` as shown in some other answers but I think it's better to know this pattern in the first place since `LiftA2` is hardwired to binary operators / functions, in other words if you have to lift a ternary operator such as `(,,)` then you need to use `LiftA3` instead. However the above pattern simply does it in the same way, like

```
λ> (,,) <$> Just 1 <*> Just 't' <*> Just "yeah"
Just (1,'t',"yeah")
```